# How do I write into YML format and reading it again with OpenCV and C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, terminal, yaml, ubuntu-18.04

I'm following an OpenCV book tutorial to write and read into File Storage. It's supposed to create a file named "**test.yml**", then store some value in it and read that file again. Here's the code from the book :

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main (int, char** argv){
        //create writer
        FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

        //save an int
        int fps = 5;
        fs << "FPS" << fps;

        //create some Mat sample
        Mat m1 = Mat::eye(2,3, CV_32F);
        Mat m2 = Mat::ones(3,2, CV_32F);
        Mat result = (m1+1).mul(m1+3);

        //write result
        fs << "Result" << result;

        //release file
        fs.release();

        //create reader
        FileStorage fs2("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);

        Mat r;
        fs2["Result"] >> r;
        cout << r << endl;
        fs2.release();
        return 0;

}
```

There's no error when I run the program, but there's no output (blank) and no *.yml file generated in my active / project working directory. If this information is relevant, I compile using CMake in terminal Ubuntu.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED :**

1. According to [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html), adding "open" is necessary when reading, so I modified reading code into this :

   ```
   int main (int, char** argv){

       //create writer
       FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

       //...

       //create reader
       FileStorage fs2.open("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);
   ```

   But still empty result.
2. Then I tried to check if there's actually any data in it. I added checking code :

   ```
   //create reader
   FileStorage fs2.open("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);

   Mat r;
   fs2["Result"] >> r;

   if (!r.data)
   {
           //Fails
           cout << "Could not open file. " << endl;
           return -1;
   }
   cout << r << endl;
   fs2.release();
   return 0;
   ```

   It returned "**Could not open file**". Turn out, there's no *.yml file generated in my active / project working directory.
3. I added cout to check if my matrices have the correct value and are actually there.

   ```
    cout << "FPS " << fps << endl;

    cout << "Matrix One :" <<"\n" << m1 << endl;
    cout << "Matrix Two :" <<"\n" << m2 << endl;
    cout << "Result :" <<"\n" << result << endl;
   ```

   The matrices were printed out correctly. But the .*yml file won't be generated.
4. I literally tried to run XML example code from [OpenCV Docs : XML/YAML Persistence](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#filestorage), and I encountered the same thing. I can run the program, there's no error but no *.yml file generated. I've also been advised debugging to investigate my code, so far GDB debugging has been not easy and I'm still working on it.

What did I miss here ?

Comment: is this the complete unmodified code from the book? There should be a `#include <iostream>` (unless `opencv.hpp` indirectly includes it, but then still it should be included in the source)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, it is unmodified, here :[https://books.google.co.id/books?id=WwYcDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=writing+to+file+storage+basic+data+persistence+and+storage&source=bl&ots=DytMN4TH_q&sig=ACfU3U1Ctjh2A1KZkgHOwF9aB6smbRDOBg&hl=id&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtltWYiPXnAhWFc30KHe3SDmIQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=writing%20to%20file%20storage%20basic%20data%20persistence%20and%20storage&f=false]. When we load "opencv.hpp" we've loaded all functions already. It's just we will load a lot more than just <iostream>.

Comment: Looks like you can list open files from gdb. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231460/gdb-howto-list-open-files using `gdb info os files`. That could help you find where the file is opening. Does the `FileStorage` object have some kind of member function that allows you to see if the file was actually opened?

Comment: @John Yes, FileStorage has this function "isOpened()" to check if the file is actually opened. I tried with it already, but the file isn't even there, it's not being generated at all. Thanks, I'll be checking the gdb page you mention.

Comment: I think I had the same issue. Did you try to generate a .xml? Does this work?

Comment: @Grillteller Yes. I have tried with .xml as well. Still not working. Also, actually someone from another forum tried to excute this code and it worked just fine on his machine. Mine's not. I havent found the problem. Probably system issue after all, not coding issue.